# Extjs4 class listeners and functions

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In this code, there are many existing function, but I have to start to make some extended ExtJS class using that functions.

How can I add an existing function to a listener of a class?

For example:

```
Ext.define("My.Grid", { 
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    //...
    initComponent: function() {
        //...
        Ext.apply(this, {
            //...
            tbar: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                icon: 'img/x.png',
                handler: function(){
                   // need to call randomOtherFunction here
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});

function randomOtherFunction () {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not really sure why you're having a problem. Just call the other function.

Comment: It says: "randomOtherFunction is not a function" - but now i have an idea, trying it and i will return and tell it, if it works... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yessss, it works! :) ... and I hope, it will be good until the old other functions go to an object.

```
function randomOtherFunction () {
    // ...
}

My.functions = {
    randomOtherFunction: function () {
        randomOtherFunction();
    }
};

Ext.define("My.Grid", { 
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    //...
    initComponent: function() {
        //...
        Ext.apply(this, {
            //...
            tbar: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                icon: 'img/x.png',
                handler: function(){
                    My.functions.randomOtherFunction();
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't really see how this answer helps others, seems very specific to your situation since you left out so many details. Probably best to delete the question.

Comment: I can't delete it: "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead."

Answer (score -1):

You have to check the scope and use it  to call the handler function.
Try the below

```
Ext.define("My.Grid", { 
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    //...
    initComponent: function() {
        //...
        Ext.apply(this, {
            //...
            tbar: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                icon: 'img/x.png',
                scope:this,
                handler:this.randomOtherFunction
            }]
        });
    }
});

function randomOtherFunction () {
    // ...
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The function is explicitly defined outside the class, so this won't work.

Comment: You have to add an event to the button and fire it in the handler.  In the other class you have to listen to that event and call the specific method.